# Why doesn't 'await' wait?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am new to await/async functions in Javascript. I wrote the following function:

```
getGoogleResults = async () => {
    const googleResultUrl = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=bakery&num=60');

    // get only Divs within results that have class of 's'
    $.getJSON(googleResultUrl, (data) => {
      const results = $(data.contents).find('div[class="g"]');
      const divs = results.find('div[class="s"]');
      console.log(data.contents); // data logged here looks fine in console
      return data.contents; 
    });
  }
```

This function works fine, I can log out the response to the console and see the data that was parsed out (top 60 Google results).

However, what I don't understand is when I call the function, I'm expecting it to wait until the promise is returned before continuing. But, that isn't the case. When I call the function, the program immediately runs the next line (a log to the console) without waiting:

```
async startProcess() {
    const googleResults = await this.getGoogleResults();
    console.log(googleResults); // this gets run immediately, produces 'undefined' in console
  }
```

And what gets logged to the console is 'undefined'. So, obviously, I'm doing something wrong, but I can't find an example that shows what that could be. It's like the program invokes the function but immediately moves on without waiting for the promise.

EDIT: I know my function is just returning `data.contents` at this point, instead of the parsed Divs. I'm just testing at this point and wanted to see results after calling the async function.

Comment: You aren't returning anything from `getGoogleResults`, so `await`ing its result results in `undefined`.

Comment: Doesn't the `return data.contents' statement return something?

Comment: The `return` statement *inside* the `$.getJSON()` callback doesn't do anything useful, and in particular it doesn't affect the return value of your `async` function.

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't affect the outer function, `getGoogleResults`, which isn't returning anything.

Comment: AH! I understand now. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: If $ is jquery you don&#39;t need return new promise like the answers suggest. Just do return $.getJSON()

Comment: @karthick you need to convert to promise `$getJSON(() => {...}).promise()`

Comment: @Ele, $.getJSON returns a deferred which is more or less compatible with the spec. Although there might be some issues with setting up the error handling. But still that can also be solved. https://jsfiddle.net/karthick6891/cu10Lxf8/, Not against the solution of new Promise(), I just feel that its unnecessary for the given case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object from the function `getGoogleResults`

```
getGoogleResults = () => { // You don't need the async keyword here
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const googleResultUrl = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=bakery&num=60');
        // get only Divs within results that have class of 's'
        $.getJSON(googleResultUrl, (data) => {
          const results = $(data.contents).find('div[class="g"]');
          const divs = results.find('div[class="s"]');
          console.log(data.contents); // data logged here looks fine in console
          resolve(data.contents); // Use the function resolve.
        });

        // Use the function reject for any errors.
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should return a Promise for your async function to actually be awaitable. Like this:

```
getGoogleResults = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const googleResultUrl = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=bakery&num=60');

      // get only Divs within results that have class of 's'
      $.getJSON(googleResultUrl, (data) => {
        const results = $(data.contents).find('div[class="g"]');
        const divs = results.find('div[class="s"]');
        console.log(data.contents); // data logged here looks fine in console
        resolve(data.contents); 
      }); //TODO call reject() on error
    }
}
```